# how to switch between output tab and code writing area in visual studio without touching mouse?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

just after running the code ,An output tab appears ,to again write the code I have to use mouse to click on code writing area to hide this tab and write code once again and hide this tab.Is there any keyboard shortcut for this task ?[here you can see that output tab which irritates me ! after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2iDJ.png)

Comment: Escape key works for me.

Answer (score 0):

just use the keyboard shortcut shift + Esc